# SQL syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im using Microsoft SQL Server which I think is T-SQL or ANSI SQL.

I want to search a database with a string.  The matches that fit the begging of the string should come first then sort alphabetically.

I.e. If the table contains `FOO`, `BAR` and `RAP`

a search for the string `'R'` should yield:

`RAP`
`BAR`

In that order.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT     Name
FROM       MyTable
WHERE      (Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%')
ORDER BY   (IF(Name LIKE @name + '%',1,0))
```

The error message is: "must declare scalar variable @name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare  @name varchar(10)
set @name='R'
SELECT     Name 
FROM       (select 'foo' as name union select 'RAP' union select 'BAR') MyTable 
WHERE      (Name LIKE '%' +  @name  + '%') 
ORDER BY   charindex(@name ,name)
```

Comment: I like this solution the best, charindex is more compact and gives a better sort ordering.

Answer (score 2):

.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @name = 'foo';

SELECT     Name
FROM       MyTable
WHERE      Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
ORDER BY   CASE WHEN Name LIKE @name + '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Comment: This was what I was trying to do with the IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you **missed** variable **declaration**:

```
DECALRE @name varchar(50) -- adjust type and length of variable
SET @name = 'phrase' -- for MSSQL 2008 you can do it in one line
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions seem to miss the "sort alphabetically" part:

```
DECLARE    @Search VARCHAR(MAX)
SET        @Search = 'R'

SELECT     0, Name 
FROM       MyTable 
WHERE      Name LIKE @Search + '%'
UNION ALL
SELECT     1, Name
FROM       MyTable
WHERE      Name like '%_' + @Search + '%'
ORDER BY   1, 2
```

Comment: This is a clever idea, I tried to do it this way to begin with, but I could not get the union working.